# Do a file containing words separated by newline and a vector of strings for those words in C++ have same size?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, sizeof

The file is of the following form:

word1
word2
word3
...

And I create vector of strings after reading those words from the file like this:

```
std::vector<string> words;
string w;
ifstream file("input");
while(getline(file,w))
    words.push_back(w);
file.close();
```

Will the size of physical memory occupied by the vector be same as the size of input file? Why?

Comment: Things to consider: The actual `std::vector` object itself needs space; The `std::string` objects themselves needs space; And the lines read by `std::getline` will not include the newline.

Answer (score 4):

> Will the size of physical memory occupied by the vector be same as the size of input file?

It depends on what do you mean by *"size of physical memory occupied by the vector"*. Size of the vector object itself is typically size of 3 pointers (or 1 pointer and 2 numbers), such as 24 bytes on a 64-bit architecture. However, the vector then dynamically allocates space for **at least** *N* string objects, where *N* is the number of file lines. Note that if you do not reserve vector space, it will likely allocate more space than for *N* strings.

Each string object has again some "internal" size (24 bytes with libc++/Clang, 32 bytes with libstdc++/GCC in my experiments).

And then, each string needs to store the text line. It might allocate memory dynamically, or for short string it might employ *small string optimization*. With dynamic memory allocations you need to take some padding into account, since dynamically allocated buffers are aligned (to 16 bytes in my environment).

You therefore cannot easily compare memory occupations here. But, generally, there would be a lot of overhead with vector of strings.

---

If you want to avoid this overhead, simply read whole file content into a single char array (vector, string) and then create an additional array with pointers to where individual lines begin.

Comment: A vector of string_views might be more appropriate than one of char *s

Answer (score 2):

The vector implementation has two memory footprints: the `sizeof(vector)` is the memory used on the stack (usually 24 bytes) and then there is the memory dynamically allocated, first by the `vector` and second by the `string` arguments.

The vector may well allocate more memory than it actually needs to hold all the strings: if you grow it by `push_back` (or `emplace_back`), it doubles the dynamically allocated memory whenever it runs out of capacity.

The strings, finally, have their own overhead: for short words (shorter than `sizeof(string)`) unused memory in string is wasted, while for long words the string must allocate dynamic memory and keep a separate pointer (causing memory overhead).

Thus, the answer is: **NO**, `vector<string>` takes more space (which may be distributed between stack and different places on the heap).